# How do I determine whether ruby can fork without excessive use of regexp?

Tags: ruby, regex, fork

Is it possible to determine whether the implementation of ruby you're running on is capable of supporting `fork`, without running a regex against `RUBY_PLATFORM` that'll expand until it [summons Cthulhu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157953/use-regex-to-find-and-replace-specific-html-tags)?

(Related question: [Ruby - How can I find out on which system my program is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170956/ruby-how-can-i-find-out-on-which-system-my-program-is-running))

**Edit**: I tried Marc-Andre's suggestion. It doesn't work for jruby with fork disabled by default:

```
192-168-1-7:~ agrimm$ jruby --1.9 -S jirb 
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.2dev"
irb(main):002:0> Process.respond_to?(:fork)
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Process.fork
NotImplementedError: fork is unsafe and disabled by default on JRuby
```

**Update**: From Marc-Andre's link, it seems wiser heads than I have grappled with this problem from the perspective of creating ruby implementations, and failed.

From the perspective of someone who's writing a ruby library, what would be the most comprehensive incantation, short of running fork and seeing if it raises an exception?

Comment: @Andrew: Just saw your edit... Indeed, JRuby has a hard time implementing this new `respond_to` behavior. I updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby 1.9:

```
Process.respond_to?(:fork)  # => true if fork is supported, false otherwise
```

For Ruby 1.8, or JRuby (which doesn't implement this currently) you'll have to actually test it.

See also this [long discussion](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/2619) on ruby-core.

Comment: Thanks for that link. Pointing to a definitive source to say "You can't do X" is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of error-prone testing against RUBY_PLATFORM or other things you could test `fork` itself:

```
def can_fork?
  pid = fork
  exit unless pid # exit the child immediately
  true
rescue NotImplementedError
  false
end
```

One downside would be if `fork` is somehow emulated which could make this check expensive.

Answer (score 0):

A [recent commit](http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/53c13f1acaa2eb05e7f418b53f6156a4f5a773e0#L2L36) to rails uses

```
Config::CONFIG['host_os'] !~ /mswin|mingw/)
```

to test whether it's not on Windows, and

```
RUBY_PLATFORM !~ /java/
```

to test whether it's not on JRuby. However, I know it's possible to enable `fork` as a command-line switch. I'd have to look into whether there's any way of telling whether it's been enabled.

I suspect macruby doesn't support, or strongly discourages, forking, and from the thread Marc-Andre refers to, you can test for it with

```
 RUBY_ENGINE != "macruby"
```

Now for all the other platforms out there... (work in progress, marking as community wiki, please feel free to edit)